# how to factorize $x^2+10yz-2xz-2xy-3y^2-3z^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

How to factorize 
$$x^2+10yz-2xz-2xy-3y^2-3z^2$$

It is expanded and we should make them into parts and factorize each part individually.

the last answer is $$(x+y-3z)(x-3y+z)$$

but how to get it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write it as $x^2 - 2 (z+y)x + (10yz-3z^2-3y^2)$. It is known how to factor [quadratic polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula). Here, the roots are $$(z+y) \pm \sqrt{(z+y)^2 - (10yz-3z^2-3y^2)}=(z+y) \pm \sqrt{4y^2-8yz+4z^2}$$
$$=(z+y) \pm 2(y-z) \in \{3y-z,3z-y\}.$$
Therefore the polynomial factors as $(x-(3y-z)) \cdot (x-(3z-y))$.

Comment: After years, I now think that this quadratic polynomial method is better and more straightforward. Exactly because of the mechanics and art analogy you used.

Answer (score 7):

One way to do it is
\begin{align*}
x^2+10yz-2xz-2xy-3y^2-3z^2&=(x^2+y^2+z^2-2xz-2xy+2yz)-(4y^2+4z^2-8yz)\\
&=(x-y-z)^2-(2y-2z)^2\\
&=(x+y-3z)(x-3y+z)
\end{align*}
where going from the second to the third line, we have used $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$.

Comment: While reading your answer, one might think that "expanding is mechanics and factoring is art" (similar to "differentiating is mechanics and integration is art"), but in *this case* we only have a quadratic polynomial (in each variable), so that factorization is mechanic. This is explained in my answer.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I agree with you. +1 for your answer.